# Fill a drawn triangle using lines

Tags: c#, draw, system.drawing, drawimage

i need to generate a new method to fill the triangle in the below code and call it separately
any advise please?

```
public void draw(Graphics g, Pen blackPen)
    {
        double xDiff, yDiff, xMid, yMid;

        xDiff = oppPt.X - keyPt.X;
        yDiff = oppPt.Y - keyPt.Y;
        xMid = (oppPt.X + keyPt.X) / 2;
        yMid = (oppPt.Y + keyPt.Y) / 2;

        // draw triangle
        g.DrawLine(blackPen, (int)keyPt.X, (int)keyPt.Y, (int)(xMid + yDiff / 2), (int)(yMid - xDiff / 2));
        g.DrawLine(blackPen, (int)(xMid + yDiff / 2), (int)(yMid - xDiff / 2), (int)oppPt.X, (int)oppPt.Y);
        g.DrawLine(blackPen, (int)keyPt.X, (int)keyPt.Y, oppPt.X, oppPt.Y);

    }
```

the method should take both of these arguments

```
public void fillTriangle(Graphics g, Brush redBrush)
    {


    }
```

Comment: There is `FillPolygon` as far as I remember ... A Polygon with 3 Points is a triangle.

Comment: You will have to create a **DrawPolygon** and then fill it with **FillPolygon**.

Comment: @Fildor so do u need to store the drawn lines into an array then give it as the second argument to the fillpolygon ?

Comment: A triangle is a Polygon defined by three points. Use `Graphics.FillPolygon()` to fill the shape. Or `GraphicsPath.AddPolygon()`. With `GraphicsPath`, you can also draw 3 lines, then call `.CloseFigure()`, then `Graphics.FillPath()`.

Comment: a) store the 3 points in three point variables!!! b) make a list<Point> of them!! c) call DrawPolygon and d) pass the list out to your fillTriangle function where you use FillPolygon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single function for the drawing, and for reduced complexity and consistency use a `GraphicsPath` object.

```
void DrawGraphics(Graphics g, Pen pen, Brush brush)
{
    float xDiff=oppPt.X-keyPt.X;
    float yDiff=oppPt.Y-keyPt.Y;
    float xMid=(oppPt.X+keyPt.X)/2;
    float yMid=(oppPt.Y+keyPt.Y)/2;

    // Define path with the geometry information only
    var path = new GraphicsPath();
    path.AddLines(new PointF[] {
        keyPt,
        new PointF(xMid + yDiff/2, yMid-xDiff/2),
        oppPt,
    });
    path.CloseFigure();

    // Fill Triangle
    g.FillPath(brush, path);

    // Draw Triangle
    g.DrawPath(pen, path);
}
```

The result is as seen below:

[image: scr]

Answer (score -1):

You just need to create an array with the dots, after that configure how the fill will be and then yes draw `FillPolygon` which is an entity to `DrawPolygon` which is just the outline.

```
    public void draw(Pen blackPen)
    {
        Graphics draw = CreateGraphics();

        Point[] points = new Point[6];
        points[0].X = 0;
        points[0].Y = 0;
        points[1].X = 150;
        points[1].Y = 150;
        points[2].X = 0;
        points[2].Y = 150;

        using (SolidBrush fillvar = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Yellow)))
        {
            draw.FillPolygon(fillvar, points.ToArray());
            draw.DrawPolygon(Pens.DarkBlue, points);
        }

    }
```

If you want to draw the `FillPolygon` inside something, as with a `PictureBox` you just have to assign it to the `Graphics draw`.

```
    Graphics draw = picturebox.CreateGraphics();
```

Above is just a practical illustration of how it works, take a look at your code. Missing just implement its xDiff, yiff, xMid, yMid coordinates.

```
    public void draw(Graphics g, Pen blackPen)
    {
        double xDiff, yDiff, xMid, yMid;

        Point[] points = new Point[6];
        points[0].X = 50;
        points[0].Y = 50;
        points[1].X = 150;
        points[1].Y = 150;
        points[2].X = 0;
        points[2].Y = 150;

        SolidBrush varbrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(100, Color.Yellow));

        fillTriangle(g, varbrush, points);
    }
```

You will have to pass the dots to fillTriangle and draw them in this method.

```
    public void fillTriangle(Graphics g, Brush varbrush, Point[] points)
    {
        g.FillPolygon(varbrush, points.ToArray());
        g.DrawPolygon(Pens.Red, points);
    }
```

Comment: Please, remove this things:`Graphics draw = CreateGraphics();` and  `Graphics draw = picturebox.CreateGraphics();`. You must use a Control's **Paint** event to draw on its surface. If you don't know why, minimize the Form the normalize it again.

Comment: @Alberto Santos the thing is , the filling has to be in a different method, so i can call it somewhere else based on the user choice